# How to handle changes in a form with a model-update using Wicket and AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, model, wicket

I have a form with many input-fields and need to handle a change to any of those input-fields; so I add a `AjaxEventBehavior` to the form, like:

```
Form<MyX> myForm = new Form<>("X", getModel());
myForm.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
         handleFormChange(...);
    }
});
```

The method `handleFormChange` gets called everytime I change some content in the input-fields of the form. But the model is not getting updated with the new value of the changed input-field of the form.

How can I get thoose model-updates? I tried `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`. It updates the model, but I cannot use it for forms, just for `FormComponents`.

Does anybody has an ideas how to handle that? TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AjaxFormSubmitBehavior you can submit the whole form on each change.

Answer (score 1):

First for on change use the dedicated `OnChangeAjaxBehavior`.

Then you can use the `Iterator` of the `form` to get all children and add then add the `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` to all `FormComponents` which will call your `handleFormChange()` on every change like this:

```
    for (Iterator it = form.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Object o = it.next();
        if (o instanceof FormComponent) {
           ((FormComponent) o).add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {

               @Override
               protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                   handleFormChange(...);
               }
           });
        }
     }
```